# Como mostrar PDF en un solo div

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, objeto, data

Tengo un listado de botones,en html, cada botón mostrará un PDF.
Dicho pdf se mostrará en un solo div o visualizador de PDFs
Es decir, al dar clic en cada boton que cambie el PDF que se visualiza.

He intentado buscar la manera pero no encuentro .
Puede ser mediante javascript.
Pero como puedo hacer que funcione, alguna idea?

Comment: El uso de la etiqueta `object` es perjudicial y se considera una mala practica, la etiqueta `<object>` no deberia ser usada, es mas, no se ni porque no la han quitado, seguro porque tiene ciertas peculiaridades que te solventan algunas cosas, pero que te vulneran la seguridad violentamente. porfavor trata de no usar la etiqueta object para mostrar un PDF en su lugar esta la etiqueta `<iframe>` para poder mostrar ese recurso o si el usuario no necesita verlo si no descargarlo la etiqueta `<a>` es majestuosa. aunque el `iframe` tambien es poco recomendado sobre todo por el consumo...

Comment: Sin embargo si no necesitas tener muchos pdf en una misma pagina los `iframe` pueden ayudarte, de lo contrario el hecho de tener muchos iframe en una sola pagina la alentejara mas que internet explorer cuando salio.

Comment: De hecho no utilizo iframe por  los riesgos de seguridad. El object era una  opcion, pero si tienes otra alternativa seria genial.No se si con el embed funcione, para mostrar PDF en el mismo DIV, al dar clic el boton

Comment: Es cierto,  pero en este caso ambos vulneran la seguridad,  aunque considero que el mayor riezgo de seguridad lo tiene la etiqueta `<object>`.